# USSD reading replies

Tags: android, ussd

I have been working a bit on reading radio logs to retrieve USSD replies, rather than the aidl,
though I am not yet sure which suits my purpose better. I am still hoping to trap menus as well as simple exchanges.

Anyway, I can now read the replies programmatically, but they still land onscreen in a system dialog that I need to press OK to dismiss.

Is there a programmatic way to dismiss this system dialog?

What I am writing is some code that will execute my own USSD (ie 3rd party from carrier) on an android used without human interfacing (there is no one present to press OK). It's used more to send info to the server than to receive info back. I did this on an old Wavecom modem ages ago, so it has been a frustration discovering how difficult this was to do in Android.

Comment: No API for USSD provided by Android.Last year, we did a project which track user calls & messages. we reach to parsing USSD message . if you want to buy solution, we will discuss.

Comment: See this answer here it shows how to use USSD http://stackoverflow.com/a/20472335/1979347

Comment: You may find more info on : http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/205928-java-ussd-api/

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI We are looking for same kinda stuff. Could you please help

Comment: @TGMCians : let us discuss through g-mail : abdennour.toumi[at]... U'r welcome

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI i don't want to discuss personal on your gmail. stackoverflow is a platform where community share things, code, solutions to developers. nobody is here to buy your solution &..don't do business here..

Comment: @TGMCians, Alright! . .so please , don't ask for payable something here

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I am not asking your solution which you want I will pay.. if you think like so then stop it.. again don't do business here. never post such like here. I will keep checking.

Comment: " don't do business here" .. @TGMCians, Alright! . .so please , don't ask for payable something here

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI if you think sharing knowledge here is just payable thing then go to hell

Answer (score 0):

In as much as the documentation is minimal, this app actually does a good job intercepting USSD responses:
https://github.com/alaasalman/ussdinterceptor

Comment: https://github.com/alaasalman/ussdinterceptor This would only be possible in an Android version earlier than 4.2.2. In 4.2.2 the IExtendedNetworkService seems to have been removed by Google due to security risk. See issue posted at Google – https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57120

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/f9abded9b7253c797af8b01102c153227b09446f%5E!/